# Marathon & Sports Event Photographers: Are they freelance or agency/company-related?

Tags: business, sports, photographer

I am currently doing my research on marathon and sports event photography. I am looking at photo services such as finisherpix.com and marathon-photos.com. Are the photographers taking photos for these sites freelance professionals or are they from certain agencies/companies? Furthermore, what's the pay structure, like how much does the photographer/agency get and how much does the company (finisherpix) get? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how specific websites work(i.e. finisherpix and marathon-photos) and is not about photography.

Comment: A photographer has quoted the rate of [$.17/photo in 2013](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3470722?page=3).

Answer (score 1):

> The FinisherPix is team is made up of people that enjoy working in a dynamic, fast-paced environment. We also LOVE what we do.
>
> We believe in creating a friendly and fun atmosphere amongst our team and business partners.
>
> If this sounds interesting to you we welcome you to contact us at [...]

http://www.finisherpix.com/service/jobs.html

I am guessing finisherpix pay their photographers, and they are most likely freelancers who have signed up to different agencies... such as this one and marathon-photos.com.

Freelance photographers often sign up to agencies, as this is another source of income, so your questions sort of answers itself.

Comment: Ohh cool thanks ! just curious what's the pay structure like for both the photographer/agency and the company(Finisherpix.com)

Comment: Couldn't answer that! I guess you could email the company for more information?